# I'm having an issue with using statement in C#

Tags: c#

```cs
// auto flush
using(var sw = new StreamWriter(compileScript)) 
{
    sw.Write(_submission.Cmd);
}

// it doesn't do auto flush
using var sw = new StreamWriter(compileScript);
sw.Write(_submission.Cmd);
```

As shown in the above code, I used the second wat according to the IDE prompt at the beginning, but there was a bug. Then I found that the bug was because I didn't flush after writing the data to file, and I immediately read the file.

this is the official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

I want to know where to explain the difference between the two ways.

Comment: What version of C# are you using? The second method was released last year with C# 8.0, so if you haven't updated then that would be why it's not working.

Comment: AutoFlush defaults to false. Show the line of code where you set it to true because I can't see it

Comment: @Oakley I don't think that's it - the question reads (to me) like the program compiled and ran but didn't write - that wouldn't have happened if the using statement was a syntax error?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you did not understand from the link, in particular "The newer using statement syntax translates to similar code. The try block opens where the variable is declared. The finally block is added at the close of the enclosing block, typically at the end of a method" (as question essentially asking to explain that sentence)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference between these two `using`s if you're on a modern enough version of C# that either way will compile and run (the way you write a `using` has no influence on the value of the AutoFlush property), other than a scope size difference; in your posted code we can definitely see the end of the `using` scope for the first way but we can't see it for the second.

Because closing a streamwriter flushes it, and disposing it closes it we can be sure of when your first streamwriter has been flushed.. But we can’t be sure when your second way has.

If, for example, you were debugging and had stepped out of the Write line and out of the `using` in the first case then your streamwriter should be flushed. It wouldn’t be this way in the second (if you were stepping over the write and then testing to see if data had been flushed)

```
//way 1
using(var sw = new StreamWriter(compileScript)) 
{
    sw.Write(_submission.Cmd);
} //ends using, closes sw, flushing data

SomeReadFileMethod(compileScript); //it can see flushed data



//way 2
using var sw = new StreamWriter(compileScript);
sw.Write(_submission.Cmd);

SomeReadFileMethod(compileScript); //sw hasn’t flushed yet because it’s still open/using scope still active
```

Neither of these are related to AutoFlush, which your code appears not to use; I think the difference is purely down to a misunderstanding of the size of scope for the first and second ways and when the code that is expecting the streamwriter to have flushed is running

Comment: Disposing a stream writer always flushes it, though. My guess is there's other code after what's presented here, and since changing to a using declaration _might_ change where `Dispose` is called, then it's pretty follows that it might also change where the flush occurs.

Answer (score 2):

As already explained, both codes are a way of writing the using statement in different ways. Its like using var instead of actual data type.

The code intent doesnt change. I personally prefer

```
Using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream)) 
 { // Work with things here }
```

As its more readable. Based on the current code, I would suggest you to use try, catch, finally to figure out the bugs in code like use finally block to close and flush the streamwriter. Once you have figure out the issue, you can revert to using the using statement.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `var` vs explicit type declaration...? It's just a matter of scope.